# How to make the curly arrow text wrap in behind text

Tags: html

Layout of my webpage (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfOLE.png)

Basically, I would like the arrow to be in behind-text.

```
<img src="/Images/84893acb1761f431efdcc11ad7a9c92f-removebg-preview.png" style="position: relative; left:5px;float: left;">
```

What should I do? Thank you. Note: Only inline css is allowed, we aren't allowed to use external and internal css.

I tried searching for google for a specific solution but couldn't find one, hope I get help here thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using absolute positioning but it would require both text and image elements to be inside a common parent div. Can you share your full HTML structure?

Comment: I would suggest using a pseudo element to position it in the background.

Comment: Do you have a live URL? we cant do anything with a img tag and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

No clue why you would be forced to use inline CSS, however here you go this is how you position an image behind a text element.

```css
/*
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
  <img src="https://cdn3d.iconscout.com/3d/premium/thumb/swerve-down-arrow-6541203-5408064.png" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;">
  <h1 style="font-size: 3rem; z-index: 3; margin-top: 200px;">This is text, very cool</h1>
</div>
```

Note that I also included CSS and commented it out, so it's easier to read what I added to what element to get the desired result.